# Flash Drive Self-Deleting Files, Computer Dectection

Tags: flash, batch-file

So, I have a flash drive that has sensitive files on it. I don't want to encrypt it, but if I have to, I will. I was just wondering if there was a way for files on the flash drive to delete themselves when opened on a computer that wasn't approved by me. Or maybe, if I could have two options for folders, and if the wrong one was opened, then the file could delete itself.? Is it possible to have a program (a batch file) run on the flash drive whenever a folder is opened on the drive? Is it even possible to have a folder/file that deletes itself without approval from the user? Is it possible to have a Task Scheduler type deal on the flash drive that could run a batch file at a certain time of day (whenever it's connected to a host, obviously)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can buy self-destructing flash drives or install software that "self destructs" your data, but these schemes simply encrypt your data and wipe the drive if you get the decrypt password wrong too many times.  You get the same effect by just encrypting your files with a strong passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an autorun file on the flash drive, but this relies on the device into which it is plugged to obey that. You would also have to worry about it being plugged in to various kinds of devices: Windows, Mac, Linux, etc., so one method probably wouldn't work for everything.

If the files really are sensitive, encryption is the way to go. If you're in a Windows-only situation, the full-disk encryption with BitLocker works quite well on a flash drive.